# pixijs swapping out an image without it jumping

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am working on a html 5 javascript game. It has a heavily textured background. I am looking at having one 3d background item and swapping it out on the fly. So in this instance we see a room with a closed door - then when a js event is fired - the image is swapped out to show an open door.

I am trying to create the function and although I can swap the image - I am unable to stop it from jumping.

so a new image path comes in - I null and remove the old backdrop and replace it with the new. I have read about adding it to the texture cache - not sure how to do that? Its my first time using pixijs

```
GroundPlane.prototype.resetBackdrop = function (imagePath) {
    if(this.backdrop) {  
        this.backdrop.alpha = 0;

        this.removeChild(this.backdrop);
        this.backdrop = null;

        this.backdrop =  PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(imagePath);
        this.backdrop.anchor.x = .5;
        this.backdrop.anchor.y = .5;/*
        this.backdrop.scale.x = 1.2;
        this.backdrop.scale.y = 1.2;*/
        this.addChildAt(this.backdrop, 0);
        this.backdrop.alpha = 1;

    }
};
```

Comment: try adding both images and using the 'visible' property to change which one shows

Comment: What do you mean by "jumping"? Do you mean it takes some time for the image to show up?

Comment: That is correct - the image appears to pop into existence - but jumps - maybe when it readjusts - rescales/repositions.

Comment: I am building a target shooting game you see - and this backdrop is essentially the room. At the start of the game the door/shutter at the back is closed, after an event in the game the door opens - the best way I have found is to swap it out with another image. I am keen to animate it as a sprite as such, but not sure where to begin here. I thought swapping out the images would be the best thing. Its complicated as you move the gun your perspective changes. This swap method retains the perspective but the backdrop jumps. Thought it may be a caching issue?

Comment: I've seen the function this.addChildAt(this.backdrop, 0); Does the 0 represent the z-index? Could I maybe load in the new graphic behind then after a call back - fade out the old frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the "jump" is that the image being swapped in takes some time to load before it can be displayed on the screen.
To prevent this, you can load the image into the TextureCache ahead of time, so when you swap images, there won't be any delay.

```
//set the initial backdrop image
this.backdrop = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("Image1.png");
this.backdrop.anchor.x = 0.5;
this.backdrop.anchor.y = 0.5;
this.backdrop.scale.x = 1.2;
this.backdrop.scale.y = 1.2;

//this will store the second image into the texture cache
PIXI.Texture.fromImage("Image2.png");

//if you need to keep track of when the image has finished loading,
//use a new PIXI.ImageLoader() instead.


GroundPlane.prototype.resetBackdrop = function (imagePath)
{
    //Update the image Texture
    this.backdrop.setTexture(PIXI.Texture.fromFrame(imagePath));
};
```